# Function to remove near close proximity geolocations geometry in R

Tags: r, geolocation, geospatial, distance

I want to remove every city which is within 20km from another city, keeping the first city. I already calculated the distance between each city and the nearest public airport.

```
geocitylist["OSA"][,c("airport_code","cityname","tmpkey","Population","latitude","longitude","distance")]

    airport_code      cityname           tmpkey Population latitude longitude   distance
 1:          OSA     Kishiwada     jp kishiwada     205563   34.467   135.367  12.103398
 2:          OSA         Izumi         jp izumi     189087   34.483   135.433  18.389912
 3:          OSA  Tondabayashi  jp tondabayashi     132875   34.500   135.600  33.600850
 4:          OSA     Kashihara     jp kashihara     126224   34.450   135.767  47.995914
 5:          OSA      Habikino      jp habikino     121052   34.534   135.583  33.238086
 6:          OSA       Kaizuka       jp kaizuka      92633   34.450   135.350  10.036157
 7:          OSA     Izumiotsu     jp izumiotsu      80773   34.500   135.400  16.417087
 8:          OSA         Tenri         jp tenri      71054   34.583   135.833  56.642112
 9:          OSA        Tanabe        jp tanabe      69564   33.733   135.367  77.976596
10:          OSA       Kashiba       jp kashiba      69391   34.535   135.709  44.241938
```

expected output (for first 10):

```
airport_code      cityname           tmpkey Population latitude longitude   distance
         OSA     Kishiwada     jp kishiwada     205563   34.467   135.367  12.103398
         OSA  Tondabayashi  jp tondabayashi     132875   34.500   135.600  33.600850
         OSA         Tenri         jp tenri      71054   34.583   135.833  56.642112
         OSA        Tanabe        jp tanabe      69564   33.733   135.367  77.976596
```

reasons for expected output (for first 10):

```
    airport_code      cityname           tmpkey Population latitude longitude   distance
 1:          OSA     Kishiwada     jp kishiwada     205563   34.467   135.367  12.103398
 2: --DELETED-- (6km from first surviving row, because it was already filtered out it won't be checked with all the other rows)
 3:          OSA  Tondabayashi  jp tondabayashi     132875   34.500   135.600  33.600850
 4: --DELETED-- (16km from first surviving row, because it was already filtered out it won't be checked with all the other rows)
 5: --DELETED-- (survived first row check but not second row check;  4km from second surviving row)
 6: --DELETED-- (2km from first surviving row, because it was already filtered out it won't be checked with all the other rows)
 7: --DELETED-- (5km from first surviving row, because it was already filtered out it won't be checked with all the other rows)
 8:          OSA         Tenri         jp tenri      71054   34.583   135.833  56.642112
 9:          OSA        Tanabe        jp tanabe      69564   33.733   135.367  77.976596
 10: --DELETED-- (survived first row check but not second row check; 11km from second surviving row)
(the third row and fourth row were >20km from each other so both were safe)
```

further explanation:

```
for all rows of the same airport_code the function would calculate the distance between each row. As far as I'm aware it only needs forward comparing. 
Here's how I made the expected output: I took the latlongs from row 1 and I plugged the pair into a distance calculator as the first pair of latlongs. For the second pair of the distance calc I plugged in the second row to see if it was closer than 20km. 
The distance was 6km so row 2 failed the check. 
Then I went and compared row 1 and row 3: pass. 
row 1 and row 4: fail. 
r1 & r5: pass. 
r1 & r6: fail. 
r1 & r7: fail. 
r1 & r8: pass. 
r1 & r9: pass. 
r1 & r10: pass. 

checking r1 is finished so there should be no other cities near r1, now we proceed to r2. 

r2 & r3:r10: skip (r2 already failed). 

now we check r3. 

r3 & r4: skip (r4 already failed). 
r3 & r5: fail. 
r3 & r6,r7: skip (r6,r7 already failed). 
r3 & r8: pass. 
r3 & r9: pass. 
r3 & r10: fail. 
r4:r7 & r5:r10: skip (r4:r7 already failed). 
r8 & r9: pass. 
r8 & r10: skip (r10 already failed). 
r9 & r10: skip (r10 already failed). 
DONE
```

My idea is to put everything in a list and then have some kind of function which will identify which rows to delete.

```
list <- split(df[, -1], df$airport_code)
require(gmt)
lapply(list, function(x) 

geodist(geocitylist$city1[i],geocitylist$city1[i],geocitylist$city2[i],geocitylist$city2[i],units="km")), something...)
```

I'm not sure where to go from here...

dput:

```
structure(list(airport_code = c("OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", 
"OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", 
"OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", 
"OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", 
"OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "OSA", 
"OSA", "OSA", "OSA", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", 
"ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", 
"ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", 
"ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", 
"ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", 
"ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", 
"ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", 
"ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", 
"ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", 
"ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", "ILO", 
"ILO"), cityname = c("Kishiwada", "Izumi", "Tondabayashi", "Kashihara", 
"Habikino", "Kaizuka", "Izumiotsu", "Tenri", "Tanabe", "Kashiba", 
"Sennan", "Sakurai", "Hannan", "Takaishi", "Osakasayama", "Hashimoto", 
"Iwade", "Kainan", "Sumoto", "Gojo", "Gose", "Tawaramoto", "Gobo", 
"Kawai", "Kumano", "Haibara", "Asuka", "Awaji", "Kamitonda", 
"Kawachinagano", "Kimino", "Koya", "Kozagawa-Cho", "Minabe", 
"Misaki", "Nachikatsuura", "Nosegawa", "Shirahama", "Susami", 
"Taiji", "Tenkawa", "Uda", "Yoshino", "Yura", "Iloilo", "Barotac Nuevo", 
"Trapiche", "Tuyom", "Inayawan", "Jordan", "Alimodian", "Guimbal", 
"Dingle", "Cabatuan", "Igbaras", "Pavia", "Cabano", "Patnongon", 
"Ungka", "Leon", "Bulata", "Tumcon", "Caliling", "Hamtic", "Belison", 
"Buray", "Cagbang", "Masaling", "Duenas", "Linaon", "Bingawan", 
"Maasin", "Igang", "Cartagena", "Tiling", "Maribong", "Napnapan", 
"Zarraga", "Concordia", "New Lucena", "Dao", "Aglalana", "Bugasong", 
"Alibunan", "Jamabalud", "Egana", "Calaya", "Constancia", "Pakiad", 
"Nueva Valencia", "Jibao-an", "Mina", "Bolilao", "San Enrique", 
"Cordova", "Lawigan", "Piape", "Aganan", "Ponong", "Gines", "Leganes", 
"Jaguimitan", "East Valencia", "Morobuan", "Atabayan", "Avila", 
"Catungan", "Ermita", "Igcocolo", "Tiwi", "Balibagan", "Sulangan", 
"Jalaud", "Tiring", "Abangay", "Guisijan", "Abilay", "Monpon", 
"Aureliana", "Tigum", "Quinagaringan", "Abaca", "Mapili", "Da-an", 
"Cabilauan", "Getulio", "Pina", "Oracon", "Badlan", "Lucmayan", 
"Cauayan", "San Jose De Buenavista"), tmpkey = c("jp kishiwada", 
"jp izumi", "jp tondabayashi", "jp kashihara", "jp habikino", 
"jp kaizuka", "jp izumiotsu", "jp tenri", "jp tanabe", "jp kashiba", 
"jp sennan", "jp sakurai", "jp hannan", "jp takaishi", "jp osakasayama", 
"jp hashimoto", "jp iwade", "jp kainan", "jp sumoto", "jp gojo", 
"jp gose", "jp tawaramoto", "jp gobo", "jp kawai", "jp kumano", 
"jp haibara", "jp asuka", "jp awaji", "jp kamitonda", "jp kawachinagano", 
"jp kimino", "jp koya", "jp kozagawa-cho", "jp minabe", "jp misaki", 
"jp nachikatsuura", "jp nosegawa", "jp shirahama", "jp susami", 
"jp taiji", "jp tenkawa", "jp uda", "jp yoshino", "jp yura", 
"ph iloilo", "ph barotac nuevo", "ph trapiche", "ph tuyom", "ph inayawan", 
"ph jordan", "ph alimodian", "ph guimbal", "ph dingle", "ph cabatuan", 
"ph igbaras", "ph pavia", "ph cabano", "ph patnongon", "ph ungka", 
"ph leon", "ph bulata", "ph tumcon", "ph caliling", "ph hamtic", 
"ph belison", "ph buray", "ph cagbang", "ph masaling", "ph duenas", 
"ph linaon", "ph bingawan", "ph maasin", "ph igang", "ph cartagena", 
"ph tiling", "ph maribong", "ph napnapan", "ph zarraga", "ph concordia", 
"ph new lucena", "ph dao", "ph aglalana", "ph bugasong", "ph alibunan", 
"ph jamabalud", "ph egana", "ph calaya", "ph constancia", "ph pakiad", 
"ph nueva valencia", "ph jibao-an", "ph mina", "ph bolilao", 
"ph san enrique", "ph cordova", "ph lawigan", "ph piape", "ph aganan", 
"ph ponong", "ph gines", "ph leganes", "ph jaguimitan", "ph east valencia", 
"ph morobuan", "ph atabayan", "ph avila", "ph catungan", "ph ermita", 
"ph igcocolo", "ph tiwi", "ph balibagan", "ph sulangan", "ph jalaud", 
"ph tiring", "ph abangay", "ph guisijan", "ph abilay", "ph monpon", 
"ph aureliana", "ph tigum", "ph quinagaringan", "ph abaca", "ph mapili", 
"ph da-an", "ph cabilauan", "ph getulio", "ph pina", "ph oracon", 
"ph badlan", "ph lucmayan", "ph cauayan", "ph san jose de buenavista"
), Population = c(205563, 189087, 132875, 126224, 121052, 92633, 
80773, 71054, 69564, 69391, 66460, 62966, 60796, 60512, 57170, 
57115, 55634, 43369, 39546, 34343, 32871, 32660, 27169, 20106, 
19517, 18472, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 387748, 11641, 11539, 11117, 9963, 8255, 7302, 7232, 6171, 
6106, 5974, 5928, 5812, 5810, 5598, 5172, 5151, 5067, 4840, 4816, 
4711, 3863, 3856, 3829, 3705, 3669, 3657, 3514, 3468, 3396, 3332, 
3308, 3258, 3253, 3091, 3059, 2893, 2868, 2828, 2798, 2742, 2723, 
2713, 2713, 2689, 2681, 2677, 2665, 2651, 2620, 2588, 2571, 2543, 
2522, 2513, 2476, 2463, 2461, 2444, 2442, 2362, 2349, 2318, 2304, 
2297, 2269, 2263, 2262, 2239, 2232, 2207, 2196, 2195, 2189, 2172, 
2168, 2153, 2139, 2104, 2085, 2077, 2063, 2054, 2045, 2041, 2024, 
0, 0), latitude = c(34.467, 34.483, 34.5, 34.45, 34.534, 34.45, 
34.5, 34.583, 33.733, 34.535, 34.348, 34.5, 34.333, 34.517, 34.517, 
34.317, 34.25, 34.15, 34.35, 34.35, 34.45, 34.55, 33.883, 34.233, 
33.904, 34.533, 34.48, 34.485, 33.691, 34.45, 34.187, 34.212, 
33.536, 33.752, 34.304, 33.578, 34.118, 33.685, 33.553, 33.602, 
34.269, 34.473, 34.365, 33.977, 10.697, 10.894, 10.684, 9.977, 
9.9, 10.658, 10.821, 10.663, 10.999, 10.879, 10.716, 10.776, 
10.587, 10.913, 10.75, 10.781, 9.86, 10.917, 9.98, 10.702, 10.838, 
10.715, 10.7, 9.982, 11.067, 9.95, 11.233, 10.892, 10.916, 9.82, 
9.974, 11.1, 10.708, 10.82, 10.508, 10.879, 10.515, 11.18, 11.044, 
11.147, 10.879, 10.747, 10.492, 10.596, 10.7, 10.511, 10.75, 
10.931, 10.862, 11.071, 10.73, 10.549, 10.729, 10.783, 11.083, 
10.933, 10.787, 11.142, 10.668, 10.626, 10.683, 10.692, 10.771, 
10.9, 10.69, 10.93, 10.8, 10.811, 10.893, 10.853, 10.967, 11.093, 
10.733, 10.912, 10.885, 10.783, 11.122, 11.134, 11.108, 11.232, 
10.861, 10.747, 10.64, 10.478, 11.141, 10.473, 9.844, 10.775), 
    longitude = c(135.367, 135.433, 135.6, 135.767, 135.583, 
    135.35, 135.4, 135.833, 135.367, 135.709, 135.268, 135.85, 
    135.25, 135.433, 135.563, 135.617, 135.317, 135.2, 134.9, 
    135.7, 135.733, 135.8, 135.15, 135.85, 136.122, 135.95, 135.82, 
    134.853, 135.408, 135.574, 135.491, 135.591, 135.79, 135.325, 
    135.159, 135.931, 135.616, 135.343, 135.479, 135.945, 135.881, 
    135.92, 135.862, 135.07, 122.564, 122.704, 122.432, 122.558, 
    122.434, 122.596, 122.431, 122.323, 122.671, 122.486, 122.266, 
    122.546, 122.7, 121.994, 122.55, 122.389, 122.402, 122.667, 
    122.481, 121.982, 121.96, 122.459, 122.499, 122.537, 122.619, 
    122.448, 122.567, 122.436, 122.639, 122.4, 122.654, 122.533, 
    122.393, 122.608, 122.55, 122.597, 121.946, 122.657, 122.066, 
    122.459, 122.621, 122.01, 122.626, 122.642, 122.467, 122.532, 
    122.5, 122.575, 122.747, 122.656, 122.401, 121.986, 121.972, 
    122.533, 122.626, 122.483, 122.589, 122.69, 122.71, 122.555, 
    122.417, 122.709, 122.015, 122.717, 122.319, 122.734, 122.517, 
    122.664, 122.748, 122.511, 122.65, 122.046, 122.5, 122.638, 
    121.977, 122.567, 122.588, 122.716, 122.739, 122.421, 122.573, 
    122.666, 122.638, 122.584, 122.52, 122.519, 122.383, 121.931
    ), distance = c(12.1033983706715, 18.3899116757047, 33.6008502207034, 
    47.9959144975438, 33.2380857241381, 10.0361570266128, 16.4170866375552, 
    56.6421123629711, 77.9765955762285, 44.2419380564569, 9.08236338629334, 
    56.1040561615424, 10.4929819561705, 19.9777109028803, 30.8756212480724, 
    36.3394509305111, 20.8088759721094, 31.0772190785225, 32.6932917835482, 
    42.6875344478932, 44.8846250107249, 52.7169940204742, 61.0971131463108, 
    59.6523210207629, 99.4873860406245, 65.7262133303869, 53.1011249132666, 
    36.3948919070862, 83.1987994010293, 30.3473005687047, 35.0284306100351, 
    39.8307891352326, 111.08591952332, 75.4085566830835, 15.7641843048534, 
    113.628384359301, 48.4569715473876, 82.9862748769935, 99.5353589260391, 
    112.155589656905, 61.030002562045, 62.1503754896085, 57.0858456256784, 
    52.5304774496695, 16.9678516007278, 23.9650848510695, 17.8622353497786, 
    95.3826087011773, 103.879664442242, 22.4451633033778, 6.93563300043443, 
    26.5105095696934, 26.7555548147453, 5.17234173583494, 28.0185700131311, 
    8.55316337771447, 35.4454504812041, 55.2125344446071, 11.1051435584871, 
    12.7732336937756, 108.581863736287, 21.121988580694, 94.7968710054594, 
    57.6888894096445, 58.2126963678581, 13.6398306134487, 14.7936754865746, 
    94.6852187356986, 29.3921004979045, 98.2460045794196, 45.1659952539469, 
    9.06298808500626, 18.3744243779213, 113.028151284642, 97.0551648543418, 
    29.980690030871, 17.6919106840833, 12.5955991980882, 36.6417019118572, 
    12.4111967318849, 69.435007170183, 42.4879227652078, 52.187645377298, 
    35.0905087142823, 14.8373207506573, 53.6199130632313, 40.567800302352, 
    30.9360522555993, 15.0583064589121, 36.0304676987285, 9.25329531036705, 
    14.0682148292176, 27.8678028846033, 31.84581492357, 15.2538294715758, 
    63.7579385401013, 58.0725944947238, 7.04357919640105, 31.3211844599149, 
    11.1674571270427, 11.6242282860789, 40.4839601053959, 29.9264324776362, 
    23.9679606967483, 18.6378718796601, 28.279040989485, 52.6660699937347, 
    25.5152625993047, 24.7961086588726, 28.3847007995859, 4.4854253785277, 
    18.7845096002248, 28.5769530854182, 2.93900551228868, 22.6670596650714, 
    56.7127941524606, 11.1375128973757, 18.0600792892105, 56.6455596931624, 
    9.77233832993428, 33.7306342063393, 41.3331620404634, 40.6417161096453, 
    45.0319001319029, 9.23116854868285, 21.130213848193, 26.6342321513515, 
    40.6723663618788, 34.3462448184846, 40.1029725617726, 110.559706361562, 
    61.7191590665721)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-132L))
```

Comment: What is the expected result with the displayed ten rows? Can you elaborate your questions a bit more?

Comment: yeah! I added an expected output. So it should be kinda like a binary search where it starts with the first one and finds cities which are less than 20km from #1 then it will filter them from the output, then it goes to #2 and searches down, then #3, etc

Comment: It seems that you want to do the search for each row. Is that right?

Comment: yeah that seems right

Comment: each row for all the cities which share the same airport_code

Comment: I am confused with the expected result. Why does the city in the 5th row become the 2nd city? Likewise, you said "only 16km from #1" in the 4th row of the expected result. Where does that result come from?

Comment: The function should calculate the distance between the first and 2nd row of the list then it should calculate the distance between 1st row and 3rd row etc until the last row in the list. if any of the distances are less than 20km then it should remove that row. after the first row is finished it should compare the 2nd row (which is the first row that was over 20km from the 1st row) with the 3rd row etc until the final row. The final row doesn't need to be compared with anything because it already was compared with everything before it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185180/discussion-between-jaksco-and-jazzurro).

Comment: the first row will always survive because there is no row above it. after the first row is done comparing the distance of itself to the other rows then it will be the second surviving row's turn to compare itself to all remaining rows below it. then it will be the third row's turn, and so on until the second to last row. the last row will never compare itself to another row because there are no rows below it. 

Is using a loop the only way to do this?

Comment: Hi, I did not have time to check here till now. I see your update. Given what you wrote in your question, any rows that are removed by the first row would not be checked later comparison. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. they wouldn't need to be checked. they can already be removed. Same for the second row or any row. And the checking never needs to go backwards because of the math's commutative property

Comment: maybe we can assign the leading row as the centre and run the remaining rows through [this](https://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/12/04/r-applying-a-function-to-every-row-of-a-data-frame/) then remove rows which are further than 20km  and loop to work on each remaining row

Comment: I've added half of an answer. hopefully it helps you see what I'm trying to do more clearly :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit4: it's working now :D

this code probably looks pretty bad but it works decently for my use case and it's not too slow

```
options("scipen"=100)
library(geosphere)
# split up data into regions
splitdt<-split(geocitylist[, -1],geocitylist$airport_code)

# function to get the total number of regions in the list
NROW(splitdt)

# function to get the total number of rows in a given region
NROW(splitdt[[1]])

## reduce cities
dat=geocitylist[FALSE,][]
currentregion=1
currentorigin=1

while (currentregion <= NROW(splitdt)){
workingregion <- as.data.frame(splitdt[[currentregion]]) ## set region
workingregion$remove = FALSE
setDT(workingregion)
plot(workingregion$longitude,workingregion$latitude)

while (currentorigin <= NROW(workingregion)) {
  # choose which row to use
  # as the first part of the distance formula
  workingorigin <- workingregion[,c("longitude","latitude")] %>% slice(currentorigin) ## set LeadingRow city
  setDT(workingorigin)

  # calculate the distance from the specific row chosen 
  # and only keep ones which are further than 20km
  workingregion<-workingregion %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(remove = 
      ifelse(distHaversine(c(longitude, latitude), workingorigin) != 0 &  # keep workingorigin city
          distHaversine(c(longitude, latitude), workingorigin) < 20000,TRUE,workingregion$remove))

  # remove matched cities
  workingregion <- workingregion[workingregion$remove!=TRUE,]

  currentorigin = currentorigin+1
}
currentregion = currentregion+1
# save results
#dat <- workingregion
dat <- rbind(dat, workingregion, fill=TRUE)
}
plot(dat$longitude,dat$latitude)
```

### edit3: I think I almost have it done.

but it doesn't work and I'm not sure why. It says subscript out of bounds

```
for (currentregion in seq_along(1:NROW(splitdt))){

workingregion <- splitdt[[currentregion]] ## set region
workingregion$remove = FALSE

for (currentorigin in seq_along(1:NROW(splitdt[[currentregion]]))){
# choose which row to use 
# as the first part of the distance formula
LeadingRow <- workingregion[,c("longitude","latitude")] %>% slice(currentorigin) ## set LeadingRow city
workingregion <- workingregion[workingregion$remove!=TRUE,]

# calculate the distance from the specific row chosen 
# and only keep ones which are further than 20km
workingregion<-workingregion %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(remove = 
    ifelse(distHaversine(c(longitude, latitude), LeadingRow) != 0 &  # keep LeadingRow city
        distHaversine(c(longitude, latitude), LeadingRow) < 20000,TRUE,workingregion$remove))
}
# save results
dat <- rbind(dat, workingregion)
}
```

### edit2: okay I figured out more of it

now I just need to add loops and/or lapply I think...

```
# split up data into regions
splitdt<-split(geocitylist[, -1],geocitylist$airport_code)

# function to get the total number of regions in the list
NROW(splitdt)

# function to get the total number of rows in a given region
NROW(splitdt[[1]])

## loop here
workingregion <- splitdt[[1]] ## set loop iteration
workingregion$remove = FALSE

# choose which row to use as the first part of the distance formula
LeadingRow <- workingregion[,c("longitude","latitude")] %>% slice(1) ## set loop iteration

## another loop here
workingregion <- workingregion[workingregion$remove!=TRUE,]

# calculate the distance from the specific row chosen and only keep ones which are further than 20km
workingregion<-workingregion %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(remove = 
    ifelse(distHaversine(c(longitude, latitude), LeadingRow) != 0 &  #keep LeadingRow city
        distHaversine(c(longitude, latitude), LeadingRow) < 20000,TRUE,workingregion$remove))
```

### edit1

Ah. I just realized this will undo the work of previous iterations because if it only appends then it will add rows back in which should have been removed so, rather than subsetting, I need to find a way to mark data as should be removed or perhaps even better, remove it from the list directly

### original answer

I have half of an answer.

```
options("scipen"=100)
library(geosphere)
setDT(dt)    

# split up data into regions
splitdt<-split(dt[, -1],dt$airport_code)

# function to get the total number of regions in the list
NROW(splitdt)

# function to get the total number of rows in a given region
NROW(splitdt[[1]])

# choose which row to use as the first part of the distance formula
LeadingRow = splitdt[[1]][,c("longitude","latitude")][1]

# calculate the distance from the specific row chosen and copy only ones which are further than 20km
df<-splitdt[[1]] %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(distanceFromLeadingRow = distHaversine(c(longitude, latitude), LeadingRow))
res<-subset(df,df$distanceFromLeadingRow > 20000)
```

now I just need to figure out how to iterate over each row and each region of all of the data and append it to a new dataframe.